# Function Callbacks Not Working on Multipage Dash/Django Application

Tags: python, django, pandas, plotly-dash

I have the application below that uses dash plotly.

If i execute this application in a single file/page application all callbacks works correctly.

But in this case I using dash multipage application with Django.

And my callbacks stop to work, the `computed-table` and `table-backlog`.

I not sure why these callbacks not working regarding that there's no error in runtime or code as well.

The objective of callback is perform calculations in dash table once values is changed by user.

Full Project: https://github.com/CaioEuzebio/DjangoDashboard/blob/master/app/as_dash.py

Application:

```
import sys
from random import randint
import base64
import io
import datetime

from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

import dash

import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as dhc

import pandas as pd
import random
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import dash_table
import dash_table_experiments
import dash_table
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import os, time
from os import listdir
import os.path, time
import datetime
import subprocess




from website.views import *





PLOTLY_LOGO = "https://p7.hiclipart.com/preview/243/790/417/doing-business-as-company-logo-name-creative-company-logo.jpg"


def dispatcher(request):
    '''
    Main function
    @param request: Request object
    '''

    app = _create_app()
    params = {
        'data': request.body,
        'method': request.method,
        'content_type': request.content_type
    }
    with app.server.test_request_context(request.path, **params):
        app.server.preprocess_request()
        try:
            response = app.server.full_dispatch_request()
        except Exception as e:
            response = app.server.make_response(app.server.handle_exception(e))
        return response.get_data()
    
    


def _create_app():

    ''' Creates dash application '''

    app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
    app.config['suppress_callback_exceptions']=True
    app.layout = dhc.Div(children=[

                dbc.Navbar(
            [
                dhc.A(
                    # Use row and col to control vertical alignment of logo / brand
                    dbc.Row(
                        [
                            dbc.Col(dhc.Img(src=PLOTLY_LOGO, height="30px")),
                            dbc.Col(dcc.Link("Home", className="ml-2", href="/home", refresh=True)),
                        ],
                        align="center",
                        no_gutters=True,
                    
                    ),href="/home"
                ),
                
                
                
                dhc.A(
                    # Use row and col to control vertical alignment of logo / brand
                    dbc.Row(
                        [
                            
                            dbc.Col(dcc.Link("Dashboard", className="ml-2", href="/dash-fig1")),
                        ],
                        align="center",
                        no_gutters=True,
                    ),
                    href="/home",
                ),
                dhc.A(
                    # Use row and col to control vertical alignment of logo / brand
                    dbc.Row(
                        [
                            
                            dbc.Col(dcc.Link("Dashboard S.", className="ml-2", href="/dash-fig2")),
                        ],
                        align="center",
                        no_gutters=True,
                    ),
                   
                ),

                 dhc.A(
                    dbc.Row([
                     dbc.Col(dcc.Link("Load New File", className="ml-2", href="/loadfile", refresh=True)), 
                     ],
                        align="center",
                        no_gutters=True,
                    ), href="/loadfile"
                 ),
                 
                  
                
                
                dbc.NavbarToggler(id="navbar-toggler"),
              
            ],
            color="dark",
            dark=True,
        ),

        dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=True),
    
        dhc.Br(),
        dhc.Br(),
        dhc.Div(id='content'),
    ])


    

    @app.callback(dash.dependencies.Output('content', 'children'),
                [dash.dependencies.Input('url', 'pathname')],               
    )
    
    def display_page(pathname):

        
        ''' '''
        if not pathname:
            return ''
        if pathname == '/':
            return dash_index()
        method = pathname[1:].replace('-', '_')
        func = getattr(sys.modules[__name__], method, None)
        if func:
            return func()
        return 'Unknown link'
    
    @app.callback(
        Output('computed-table', 'data'),
        [Input('computed-table', 'data_timestamp')],
        [State('computed-table', 'data')])
    def update_columns(timestamp, rows):
        for row in rows:
            try:
                if row['Unidades Pendentes'] != 0:
                    row['UPH_BPI_vs_Head'] = float(row['UPH_BPI_vs_Perfil']) * float(row['Head_Disponível'])
                    row['ETA_Geral'] = float(row['Unidades Pendentes']) / float(row['UPH_BPI_vs_Head'])
                    row['Delta_Hora'] = float(row['Horas_Disp']) - float(row['ETA_Geral'])
                    row['Risco_Aging'] = float(row['Delta_Hora']) * float(row['UPH_BPI_vs_Head'])
                else:
                    row['UPH_BPI_vs_Head'] = "Completed"
                    row['ETA_Geral'] = "Completed"
                    row['Delta_Hora'] = "Completed"
                    row['Risco_Aging'] = "Completed"
                    row['UPH_BPI_vs_Perfil'] = "Completed" 
                    row['Head_Disponível'] = "Completed"
                    row['Horas_Disp'] = "Completed" 
            except:
                row['ETA_Geral'] = 'N/A'
                
        return rows


    



    @app.callback(
        Output('table-backlog', 'data'),
        [Input('table-backlog', 'data_timestamp')],
        [State('table-backlog', 'data')])
    def update_columns(timestamp, rows):
        for row in rows:
            try:
                if row['Unidades Pendentes'] != 0:
                    row['Delta Hora'] = float(row['Horas Disp']) - float(row['ETA'])
                    row['Risco Aging'] = float(row['Delta Hora']) * float(row['UPH'])
                else:
                    row['ETA'] = "Completed"
                    
            except:
            
                row['ETA'] = row['ETA']
        return rows

    return app


    
    
    

  
    



def dash_fig1():

    #pandas code
   
    return  dhc.Div([
            dhc.Div([ dhc.H2(children= 'Nome Do Aqrquivo: ' + filename ),
            dhc.H2(children= "Date created: " + dataa),
            
            ],style={'textAlign': 'center',
                            'align-items': 'center',
                            'fontSize': 12,
                            'width': '100%',
                            'display': 'block',
                            'align-items': 'center',
                            'justify-content': 'center',
                            'boxShadow': '0 0 14px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
                            'padding': '30px 20px',
                            'marginBottom': 50} ),
            dhc.Div([
            dhc.Div([ 

                dhc.H2(children = "Perfil Por Canal",
                    style = {'textAlign' : 'center',}),

                dhc.Br(""),
            
                    
            dash_table.DataTable(
                    id='table1',
                    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in dforderbypn.columns],
                    data=dforderbypn.to_dict('records'),
                    style_table={'textAlign': 'center'},
                    style_as_list_view=True,
                    style_cell={'padding': '5px','fontSize': 12, 'textAlign': 'center'},
                    style_header={
                        'backgroundColor': 'Gainsboro',
                        'fontWeight': 'bold',
                        'fontSize': 12},
                    export_format='xlsx',
                    export_headers='display',
                    merge_duplicate_headers=True


                ),

            ]

                    ,style={'textAlign': 'center',
                            'align-items': 'center',
                            'fontSize': 12,
                            'width': '100%',
                            'display': 'block',
                            'align-items': 'center',
                            'justify-content': 'center',
                            'boxShadow': '0 0 14px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
                            'padding': '30px 20px'}),
                
                    ],style={'textAlign': 'center' }),      
                        
            #Tabela De Perfil Por Canal/>        

                    
                    


            #Tabela De Desempenho Por Canal<

            dhc.Div([
            dhc.Div([ 

                dhc.H2(children = "UPH / ETA  Médio Por Canal",
                    style = {'textAlign' : 'center',}),

                dhc.Br(""),
            
                    
            dash_table.DataTable(
                    id='table1',
                    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in dfordertype.columns],
                    data=dfordertype.to_dict('records'),
                    style_table={'textAlign': 'center'},
                    style_as_list_view=True,
                    style_cell={'padding': '5px','fontSize': 12, 'textAlign': 'center'},
                    style_header={
                        'backgroundColor': 'Gainsboro',
                        'fontWeight': 'bold',
                        'fontSize': 12},
                    export_format='xlsx',
                    export_headers='display',
                    merge_duplicate_headers=True


                ),

                    ],style={'textAlign': 'center',
                            'align-items': 'center',
                            'fontSize': 12,
                            'width': '100%',
                            'display': 'block',
                            'align-items': 'center',
                            'justify-content': 'center',
                            'boxShadow': '0 0 14px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
                            'padding': '30px 20px'}),
                
                    ],style={'textAlign': 'center', 'marginTop': '15px'}),      
                    

                    
            #Tabela De Desempenho Por Canal/>

                
                    
                    
            #Planejamento Estilizado<        
            dhc.Div([
            dhc.Div([ 

                    dhc.H2(children = "Planner - Suporte",
                    style = {'textAlign' : 'center',}),

                dhc.Br(""),
            
                    
                dash_table.DataTable(
                    id='computed-table',
                    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in dfplano.columns ],
                    data=dfordertype.to_dict('records'),
                    editable=True,
                    style_table={'textAlign': 'center'},
                    style_as_list_view=True,
                    style_cell={'padding': '5px','fontSize': 12, 'textAlign': 'center'},
                    style_header={
                        'backgroundColor': 'Gainsboro',
                        'fontWeight': 'bold',
                        'fontSize': 12},
                    export_format='xlsx',
                    export_headers='display',
                    merge_duplicate_headers=True


                ),

                    ],style={'textAlign': 'center',
                            'align-items': 'center',
                            'fontSize': 12,
                            'width': '100%',
                            'display': 'block',
                            'align-items': 'center',
                            'justify-content': 'center',
                            'boxShadow': '0 0 14px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
                            'padding': '30px 20px'}),
                
                    ],style={'textAlign': 'center',
                            'marginTop': '15px',
                            'display': 'block'}),
            #Planejamento Estilizado/>


                    
                    
            # Tabela Gerenciamento de Backlog<      
                    
            dhc.Div([
            dhc.Div([ 
                dhc.H2(children = "Status Por Cut Off",
                    style = {'textAlign' : 'center',}),

                dhc.Br(""),
            
                    
                dash_table.DataTable(
                    id='table-backlog',
                    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in tabelaback.columns ],
                    data=tabelaback.to_dict('records'),
                    editable=True,
                    style_table={'textAlign': 'center'},
                    style_as_list_view=True,
                    style_cell={'padding': '5px','fontSize': 12, 'textAlign': 'center'},
                    style_header={
                        'backgroundColor': 'Gainsboro',
                        'fontWeight': 'bold',
                        'fontSize': 12},
                    export_format='xlsx',
                    export_headers='display',
                    merge_duplicate_headers=True


                ),

                    ],style={'textAlign': 'center',
                            'align-items': 'center',
                            'fontSize': 12,
                            'width': '100%',
                            'display': 'block',
                            'align-items': 'center',
                            'justify-content': 'center',
                            'boxShadow': '0 0 14px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
                            'padding': '30px 20px'}),
                
                    ],style={'textAlign': 'center',
                            'marginTop': '15px',
                            'display': 'block'}),
                    
                    
                    
            # Tabela Gerenciamento de Backlog/>

            
                

                
            #Prod Hora Estaao<

                
            dhc.Div([
                dhc.Div([ 

                        dhc.H3(children = "Produção Por Hora (Estação)",
                        style = {'textAlign' : 'center',}),

                        dhc.Br(""),

                        dcc.Graph(id = 'GrapGo2', figure = figure3),
                        ],style={'textAlign': 'center',
                                'align-items': 'center',
                                'fontSize': 12,
                                'width': '100%',
                                'display': 'block',
                                'align-items': 'center',
                                'justify-content': 'center',
                                'boxShadow': '0 0 14px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
                                'padding': '30px 20px'}),

                        ],style={'textAlign': 'center',
                                'marginTop': '15px',
                                'display': 'block'}),    
                
            #Prod Hora Estacao/> 
                    
            

                
            #Prod Hora Operador<

                
            dhc.Div([
                dhc.Div([ 

                        dhc.H3(children = "Produção Por Hora (Pessoa)",
                        style = {'textAlign' : 'center',}),

                        dhc.Br(""),

                        dcc.Graph( id = 'GrapGo3', figure = figure4),
                        ],style={'textAlign': 'center',
                                'align-items': 'center',
                                'fontSize': 12,
                                'width': '100%',
                                'display': 'block',
                                'align-items': 'center',
                                'justify-content': 'center',
                                'boxShadow': '0 0 14px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
                                'padding': '30px 20px'}),

                        ],style={'textAlign': 'center',
                                'marginTop': '15px',
                                'display': 'block'}),    
                
            #Prod Hora Operador/>     
                

            
                
            #Medias moveis<
            dhc.Div([
                dhc.Div([ 

                        dhc.H3(children = "Médias Mveis (10, 20 e 30 periodos)",
                        style = {'textAlign' : 'center',}),

                        dhc.Br(""),

                        dcc.Graph(id = 'GrapGo4',figure = figuremm),
                        ],style={'textAlign': 'center',
                                'align-items': 'center',
                                'fontSize': 12,
                                'width': '100%',
                                'display': 'block',
                                'align-items': 'center',
                                'justify-content': 'center',
                                'boxShadow': '0 0 14px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
                                'padding': '30px 20px'}),

                        ],style={'textAlign': 'center',
                                'marginTop': '15px',
                                'display': 'block'}), 

            #Medias moveis/>



            #Media 10 intervalos<
            dhc.Div([
                dhc.Div([ 

                        dhc.H3(children = "Médias Móveis - 10 Intervalos por canal",
                        style = {'textAlign' : 'center',}),

                        dhc.Br(""),

                        dcc.Graph(id = 'GrapGo4',figure = figure7),
                        ],style={'textAlign': 'center',
                                'align-items': 'center',
                                'fontSize': 12,
                                'width': '100%',
                                'display': 'block',
                                'align-items': 'center',
                                'justify-content': 'center',
                                'boxShadow': '0 0 14px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
                                'padding': '30px 20px'}),

                        ],style={'textAlign': 'center',
                                'marginTop': '15px',
                                'display': 'block'}), 

            #Media 10 intervalos/>




            #Unidades Recebidas Vs Processadas/hora<
            dhc.Div([
                dhc.Div([ 

                        dhc.H3(children = "Unidades Recebidas Vs Processadas por Hora (Drop)",
                        style = {'textAlign' : 'center',}),

                        dhc.Br(""),

                        dcc.Graph(id = 'GrapGo4',figure = figurefd),
                        ],style={'textAlign': 'center',
                                'align-items': 'center',
                                'fontSize': 12,
                                'width': '100%',
                                'display': 'block',
                                'align-items': 'center',
                                'justify-content': 'center',
                                'boxShadow': '0 0 14px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
                                'padding': '30px 20px'}),

                        ],style={'textAlign': 'center',
                                'marginTop': '15px',
                                'display': 'block'}), 
            #Unidades Recebidas Vs Processadas/hora/>


            


            #UPPH Chart<
            dhc.Div([
                dhc.Div([ 

                        dhc.H3(children = "Unidade Produzidas Por Pessoa (Hora)",
                        style = {'textAlign' : 'center',}),

                        dhc.Br(""),

                        dcc.Graph(id = 'GrapGo4',figure = figure52)
                        ],style={'textAlign': 'center',
                                'align-items': 'center',
                                'fontSize': 12,
                                'width': '100%',
                                'display': 'block',
                                'align-items': 'center',
                                'justify-content': 'center',
                                'boxShadow': '0 0 14px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
                                'padding': '30px 20px'}),

                        ],style={'textAlign': 'center',
                                'marginTop': '15px',
                                'display': 'block'}), 
            #UPPH chrta/>







            ], style={'marginBottom': 50, 
                        'marginTop': 50, 
                        'textAlign': 'center', 
                        'padding': '30px 20px', 
                        'align-items': 'center' }),



            ], style={'marginLeft': 50, 
                        'marginRight': 50, 
                        'display':'block', 
                        'textAlign': 'center', 
                        'align-items': 'center',
                        'padding': '30px 20px'})

        



    


def dash_fig2():
    


    return dhc.Div([
            dhc.Div([
                dhc.Div(children=[dhc.H1('Dash 2')
                                
                                
                                
                                
                                ],style={'textAlign': 'center',
                                'align-items': 'center',
                                'fontSize': 12,
                                'width': '100%',
                                'display': 'block',
                                'align-items': 'center',
                                'justify-content': 'center',
                                'boxShadow': '0 0 14px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
                                'padding': '30px 20px'}),
            
            dhc.Div([
            dhc.Div([ 

                    dhc.H2(children = "Planner - Suporte",
                    style = {'textAlign' : 'center',}),

                dhc.Br(""),
            
                    
                dash_table.DataTable(
                    id='computed-table',
                    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in dfplano.columns ],
                    data=dfordertype.to_dict('records'),
                    editable=True,
                    style_table={'textAlign': 'center'},
                    style_as_list_view=True,
                    style_cell={'padding': '5px','fontSize': 12, 'textAlign': 'center'},
                    style_header={
                        'backgroundColor': 'Gainsboro',
                        'fontWeight': 'bold',
                        'fontSize': 12},
                    export_format='xlsx',
                    export_headers='display',
                    merge_duplicate_headers=True


                )

                    ],style={'textAlign': 'center',
                            'align-items': 'center',
                            'fontSize': 12,
                            'width': '100%',
                            'display': 'block',
                            'align-items': 'center',
                            'justify-content': 'center',
                            'boxShadow': '0 0 14px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
                            'padding': '30px 20px'}),
                
                    ],style={'textAlign': 'center',
                            'marginTop': '15px',
                            'display': 'block'}),



            ], style={'marginBottom': 50, 
            'marginTop': 50, 
            'textAlign': 'center', 
            'padding': '30px 20px', 
            'align-items': 'center' }),



            ], style={'marginLeft': 50, 
                        'marginRight': 50, 
                        'display':'block', 
                        'textAlign': 'center', 
                        'align-items': 'center',
                        'padding': '30px 20px'})








def dash_fig3():

    return 'a'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = _create_app()
    app.run_server(threaded=True, dev_tools_hot_reload=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

In a multipage application, you can put all your callbacks in a single py file say callbacks.py. If you have split your multipage app as suggested in the documentation of dash, and have an app.py, index.py, you need to have in your callback.py

```
from app import app
```

Then in the index.py you need to have

```
import callback
```

Try to separate out the code this way and ensure to have the import callback in index.py and it should work.

Comment: thank you for advise. I will try this mode and return my results.

Comment: I tryed byt i not get result, i thin is because i using django as well.

Comment: could you post snippets of how you have separated into multiple files for the app?
Also try to print what you get from the clicks in the callback, it will help with debugging